# How to iterate over a XPath in HTML format using lxml and python?

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, lxml

I want to iterate `//span[@class="postNum and contains(text(),1)]`
 This xpath over the range of 1 to 10 and store it in a variable. I want it to be done in HTML format and not XML.
pseudo code:

```
for e in range(1,11):
     xpathvar[e]='//span[@class="postNum and contains(text(),**e**)]'
```

how to implement this so that xpathvar[1] will contain the first xpath with e=1. I cannot do this because the element in RHS is a string.

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: post your input fragment

Comment: You may try `for e in tree.xpath('//span[@class="postNum" and contains(text(),1)]')`. But as others have pointed out you need to update your question with input example for proper response.

Answer (score 0):

As Prem wrote in comments (copied for visibility, I was close to not find the response):

```
for e in tree.xpath('//span[@class="postNum" and contains(text(),1)]'):
    something_with(e)
```

Answer (score -2):

I solved it myself. What I wanted to do was with using slice, I wanted to traverse to all xpath using iteration where the iterative will be in digits coming from for loop.

Comment: This is not a response but a comment. **Better add the code** that resolve the issue